# Width of edge of the bars in R plots

Tags: r

Is there a way to set the width the the edge of the bars in R plots?
For example when  I set

```
test <- read.csv(file="test4.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE)
pdf(file="test.pdf", height=4, width=6)
barplot(as.matrix(test[,2:ncol(test)]), col=heat.colors(10), space=0.5)
dev.off()
```

I get this.

[image: This is the output]

But the edges of all the bars are very thick compared to the width of the bars themselves, hence the high level of black at the bottom and in the smaller bars.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the line width before plotting.

```
opar <- par(lwd = 0.3)
```

This will make thinner bars but not affect your axes (as they are set separately).

Comment: You can also set `border = NA` in the `barplot` call to omit the borders entirely.

Comment: Interestingly, setting `lwd` inside the call to `barplot`, e.g., `barplot(runif(1e2), lwd = 0.3)` changes the thickness of the y-axis but not the bars.

Comment: @RichieCotton true, interesting observation